# UglifyJS: concat and minify or viceversa?

Tags: javascript, deployment, uglifyjs

I'm writing an app that uses many JS files. Underscore, Backbone, jQuery, jQuery plugins for sliders, several files for models, routers, collections and views.

In my dev machine, I load every file separately, but in production I use only one JS file (minified, gziped, less http req, etc.).

**In my build process, each file in minified with UglifyJS and then concat into prod.js. Is this the correct way to build that file? Or should I concat each file into prod.js and then minify with UglifyJS?**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This depends on the algorithms used, but generally I would first concatenate and then minify.

Answer (score 23):

I tested the output of each method using [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com).

### Test Setup

I used 9 JavaScript files totaling **19.15 kB** when concatenated (not minified). Each file starts with a `'use strict';` statement.

### Results:

- Concatenate => Uglify: **7.993 kB**
- Uglify => Concatenate: **8.093 kB**
- *Difference:* **0.1 kB**

### Notes:

- Concatenate => Uglify strips **8 of the 9** `'use strict';` statements
- Uglify => Concatenate preserves all `'use strict';` statements
- A single `'use strict';` statement is **13 bytes**. 8 × 13 bytes = 104 bytes, which accounts for the 0.1 kB difference.

### Final Thoughts:

**Use whichever order you prefer.**

The difference between these two processes is **negligible**. Concatenate => Uglify could (theoretically) produce (barely noticeably) smaller files if both of the following are true:

- Several of the individual files start with a `'use strict';` statement
- There are *many* individual files

---

Here's the `gulpfile.js` I used:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  concat = require('gulp-concat'),
  uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var files = [
  '!app/scripts/**/*Spec.js', // Exclude test files
  'app/scripts/**/*.js'
];

// Register tasks
gulp.task('concat-min', function() {
  return gulp.src(files)
    .pipe(concat('script.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('min-concat', function() {
  return gulp.src(files)
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('script.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: Nice test, though in the real world, you should never have global "Use Strict" statements, that is a huge pita to deal with.

I'm considering flipping from Concat+Uglify to Uglify+Concat, as when I get syntax errors, finding them is a pain when the error literally reads "Unexpected token, line 19257"

Answer (score 2):

I'd be surprised if either way round made a significant difference to the overhead of a user's request.

I'd also suggest that concatenating all these frameworks into one file may actually *increase* the overhead for each user.

Why?

When using a popular/common framework such as jQuery etc. it makes sense to host it on a CDN, such as [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jqueryUI) to benefit from caching the file - if a user's visited a website that also made use of jQuery they won't need to download it at all! Not to mention decreased geographic latency.

So, by creating your own unique file you're making it much more likely that the user will have to download the entire thing.

Comment: I would rather go for combine first. For reasons mentioned by RichardJ and HotHeadMartin, or put it simplier it's safer and more effective. Concerning CDN I wouldn't count much on it.

Comment: Also, you can make more parallel connections when you use a CDN. In my case, I'm using a webview, so there is zero chance that the file will be pre cached.

I concatenate then uglify, but for the sake of sanity when I have a syntax error, I think uglifying then concatenating is a better route.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you use [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html), using that lib you can make packages or one minimized and unified file. Please read the **optimization tool**.

However, as Widor told you, It's not a good idea join ALL the files into one. Many of those libs performs better using the google api (CDN) if you always will use your app online

Answer (score 1):

I would alway put them all into one then minify.

One thing i have started doing is to run it though http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/ first i know it sounds count-intuitive but one of the things it does is store all string in an array ok an ugly array but stops string repetition then when you go to Your minified, i use Google Closure compiler it will then tidy the strings up and you often end up with a better minified file

Comment: I tried to implement this technique in UglifyJS (I mean storing strings separately to avoid repetition) and noticed that after gzip the compressed file was reliably bigger than without messing with strings.

Answer (score 0):

It won't make much difference, since the toplevel statements (and variables &c.) aren't touched.

However, when using the `--lift-vars` option, it could change. It depends heavily on your code.

Answer (score 0):

Order would not matter much assuming you have less globals floating around. There would be very minimal file size difference. My personal preference is to Concatenate and then Uglify which allows you to generate better and accurate sourcemaps rather than other way round. (This is because sourcemaps change with each transformation). I am wondering what is the purpose of uglifying smaller files and then concatenating. Basically, it is up to you and choice is yours. Concatenating and Uglifying seems more satisfactory and less error prone